# Android wifi: handler msg not working

Tags: android, tcp, client, wifi, handler

I would like to ask a question about my code in Wifi client communication. I am communicating with a Raspberry Pi as server.
The architecture of my code is:

- Main Activity: I have the Handler class and I launch in the OnCreat the first Thread (Thread1) that takes care of establishing the wifi connection.

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public int serverPort = 40000;
  public String serverIP = "10.177.86.212";
  public WiFiConnector wifiConnection;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  editTextWE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_WE);

  wifiConnection = new WiFiConnector(serverIP, serverPort);

  Handler mHandler = new MyHandler();

  WiFiConnector.Thread1 = new Thread(new WiFiConnector.Thread1(mHandler,true));
  WiFiConnector.Thread1.start();
  }

  private class MyHandler extends Handler {
  private byte[] bytes = null;

  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        bytes = msg.getData().getByteArray("KEY");
        if(bytes!= null){
          for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
              Log.d("Data received", "value " + (0xFF & bytes[i]) );
          }

          for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
              editTextWE.setText(editTextWE.getText()+ "Server says: " + bytes.length + " "+ (0xFF & bytes[i]) + "\n");
          }
      }
  }
  }
  }
  ```

  - WifiConnector class: Thread1 and Thread2 are sharing the handler coming from the Main Activity. Thread1 send a command to Raspberry Pi to let it start sending data. Thread2 is dedicated to read data received from the server.

    ```
    public class WiFiConnector {

    static String serverIP;
    static int serverPort;
    public static Thread Thread1 = null;

    //Constructor
    public WiFiConnector(String IP, int port) {
    serverIP = IP;
    serverPort = port;
    }

    public static class Thread1 extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private Handler handler1;
    boolean firsttime = false;
    OutputStream out ;

    public Thread1(Handler handler_1, boolean firsttime) {
    this.handler1 = handler_1;
     this.firsttime = firsttime;
    }

    public void run() {
    Socket socket = null;

    try {

        //Writing to a Socket
        InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);

        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        if(firsttime){
        //I send "B" to Raspberry to let him start sending data
        out.write("B".getBytes());
        this.fisrttime = false;
        }

        Thread2 comThread = new Thread2(socket, handler1);
        new Thread(comThread).start();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }

    public static class Thread2 implements Runnable {

    public Socket clientSocket;
    private Handler handler_2;
    public DataInputStream in;
    public byte[] bytes = new byte[13];
    public Message msg;

    public Thread2(Socket clientSocket, Handler handler2) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.handler_2 = handler2;
    }

     public void run() {

     while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

        try {

            if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                Looper.prepare();
            }

            this.in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            in.readFully(bytes);

            if (in != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
                    Log.d("Data received", "valuewifi " + (0xFF & bytes[i]) );
                }

                msg = new Message();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putByteArray("KEY", bytes);
                msg.setData(b);
                handler_2.sendMessage(msg);
            } else {
                Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1(handler_2,false));
                Thread1.start();
                return;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Looper.loop();
    }
    }
    }
    ```

NOW THE PROBLEM IS:
I am receiving correctly my data (package of 13 bytes each) from Raspberry Pi, indeed:

```
Log.d("Data received", "valuewifi " + (0xFF & bytes[i]) );
```

prints correctly my values. Then I create the message to be sent to the handler in MainActivity. the Bundle contains (I have verified) the same values of the input stream received, but the message printed in the Handler of the MainActivity:

```
Log.d("Data received", "value " + (0xFF & bytes[i]) );
```

substitutes the first byte value of each message (I am trying to get 2 package each communications with the RPi) with 66 that actually is the ASCII code of "B" that I sent to start the data sending from Raspberry Pi.

PLEASE DO YOU HAVE ANY IDEA ON WHY THIS IS HAPPENING?
Many thanks for your help in advance!:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found that in Thread2 if I put

```
public byte[] bytes = new byte[13];
```

inside the run{..} before

```
in.readFully(bytes);
```

The exchange of message happens perfectly. Otherwise I only get in MainActivity the last package of byte received from the server.

Any suggestion on why does it happen?
Thanks!